# ServiceStack. Basic authentication. Service method does not always check authentication

Tags: servicestack, basic-authentication

I have a service method which is marked with [Authenticate] attribute and accepts only GET requests. I am using ServiceStack.Net built-in basic authentication. I also have two console applications which call the service method. The first application sends UserName and Password. The second application does NOT send UserName and Password. Both of the applications do not send any cookies (ss-id, ss-pid).

Here is an example of the request:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Host: local.dev
Content-Length: 25
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"Email":"user@test.org"}
```

My issue is: if I run the first application first and then the second one. The second application fetches the same data as the first one, but I expect to have "Unauthorized" as a response.

```
//AppHost.cs
var cacheClient = new MemoryCacheClient();
Container.Register<ICacheClient>(cacheClient);

var authUserSession = new AuthUserSession();
var authProviders = new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider() };

var authFeature = new AuthFeature(() => authUserSession, authProviders);
authFeature.IncludeAssignRoleServices = false;
Plugins.Add(authFeature);

var userRepository = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
Container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepository);

//internal method which finally creates a user and puts it to the repository
//using method repository.CreateUserAuth(userAuth, password);
AddUserToRepository();



//Consumers
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://local.dev");
//the following two lines are commented out in the second application
client.UserName = "admin";
client.Password = "pass123";

var data = new { Email= "user@test.org" };
var response = client.Get<object>("/Test", data);
```

Please help me to understand what causes the issue.
Thank you.

Comment: What happens when application 2 is run before application 1 is run? Does it get unauthorised response then? If the wrong credentials are used in application 1 does it get the unauthorised message? After each application calls the service are any cookies set? Are any of the cookies the same?

Comment: Hi Scott. When application #2 is run before application #1, I get "Unauthorized" response. In case when I use wrong credentials in application #1 and run it first time, I get "Unauthorized" response. In case if I run application #1 with wrong credentials after I run application #1 with right credentials, I get the content (not "Unauthorized" response). Thank you.

Comment: So can you post the fiddle of app1, and then the fiddle of app2. So we can see the header for app1 request which succeeds and the header for app2 that succeeds but shouldn't. Making this comparison should rule out a client side issue.